# bug is creating multiple users with google auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net mvc 5 site currently hosted on windows azure. 
Occasionally (normally after I have rolled out or deployed to azure) the authentication seems to bug out.

I try to log in with my google account and I get weird redirect loops where I hit login, and it takes me straight back to the login page. This is normally fixed by restarting the site on windows azure again.

Every now and again though, it will redirect back from google and ask me to enter my username to complete the registration process. It does this on my google account that has already been registered. It is registering the same google account twice or sometimes even three times.

Its happened to myself and my users and I only hear about it when someone contacts me and tells me they've lost all their stuff linked to their profile on my site.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? I'm using the bog standard login / auth controller with an mvc5 project.

EDIT ::

my url is www.dev-score.com, but it also responds to just simply dev-score.com
could it be the fact that some people register on www.dev-score.com and then try to log in with simply dev-score.com or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry everyone, i feel kind of stupid now.

the reason this is happening is because of the different domains, not different url's.
by default azure also has a ".azurewebsites.net" domain that a few of my users were using while my .com domain was propagating.

when i switched to my .com domain, and disabled my .azurewebsites.net domain they all had to re-register, as google (rightfully) thinks that this is a new website.

these are the people that were experiencing that bug and i had to manually move their stuff over to their new accounts. every now and again a user from that period comes back to the site and logs in and has to go through this process again, so it seemed like an intermittent bug but its not, its only a bug to those few users that registered during that small window and haven't been back to the site since.